# Ask poll on Facebook using graph api explorer

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, explorer

I am trying to create a new Question with Graph Api Explorer , how to include the array value in the options[] parameter . Its giving me response as

{
  "error": {
    "type": "Exception", 
    "message": "Please add at least two options.", 
    "code": 1525025
  }
}

How to include the array values in the graph api explorer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Eventually i was able to do so , below is the request format for testing out posting of questions through Graph Api Explorer

question => "your Question" 
option => ['123','1342','1'] 
allow_new_options  => true or false // only two  values accepted.

This is the perfect request example to post a question on facebook.
```

Comment: That's not really sample code, it's just three pseudocode variable assignments

Comment: I have just given the format which can be tried out on Graph Api Explorer.

Comment: There's some useful information here https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/